# Do pipeline variables persist between runs?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I'm doing a simple data flow pipeline between 2 cosmos dbs. The pipeline starts with the dataflow, which grabs the pipeline variable "LastPipelineStartTime" and passes that parameter to the dataflow for the query to use in order to get all new data where c._ts >= "LastPipelineStartTime". Then, on data flow success, updates the variable via Set Variable to the pipeline.TriggerTime(). Essentially so I'm always grabbing new data between pipeline runs.

My question is: it looks like the variable during each debug run reverts back to its Default Value of 0, and instead grabs everything each time. Am I misunderstanding or using pipeline variables wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i know,the variable which is set in the `Set Variable Activity` has it's own life cycle: during current execution of pipeline.Any change of variable can't persist until next execution stage.

To implement your needs,pls refer to my workarounds as below:

1.If you execute ADF pipeline in the schedule,you could just pass the schedule time as parameter into it to make sure you grab new data.

2.If the frequency is random,persist the trigger time into other residence(e.g. simple file in the blob storage),before data flow activity,use [`LookUp Activity`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-lookup-activity) to grab that time from blob storage file.

Comment: Aw that's a shame, was really hoping the variable would persist. I update the variable at the end of a successful run so in case an hourly run isn't successful, the next run will go back two hours to not miss any data. I'll look into your second suggestion, thanks!

Comment: How would you go about "persisting the trigger time" from within the pipeline? I just posted that question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64971514/how-do-i-store-run-time-data-in-azure-data-factory-between-pipeline-executions) fyi